# ASP.NET MVC, caching with document.body.appendChild

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, caching

For an MVC ASP.NET application, I am adding a javascript file to the `_Layout.cshtml` file in the following manner -

> ```
>         function loadJS() {
>
>             var el = document.createElement("script");
>             el.src = "/Scripts/script.js";
>             document.body.appendChild(el);
>         }
>
>         if (window.addEventListener)
>             window.addEventListener("load", loadJS, false);
>         else if (window.attachEvent)
>             window.attachEvent("onload", loadJS);
>         else window.onload = loadJS;
> ```

The purpose of this is to only load the script after the DOM has loaded.

Two questions -

1. Will `script.js` be cached by the first page that uses `_Layout.cshtml`?
2. If `script.js` *is* cached, does that mean all the following pages that use `_Layout.cshtml` will not have to retrieve `script.js` from the server? That the pages that use `_Layout.cshtml` will be able to use the client side cached version of `script.js`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when the file is requested, the file will be cached by the browsers. Then the next time the file is requested, the browser will first check its cache and use that one instead of making a request to the server.